# Azure Kubernetes LoadBalancer forward requests to all instances

Tags: azure, kubernetes, load-balancing, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I have a service using Azure Kubernetes cluster and AKS load balancer.
I want to forward some HTTP(client) requests to all instances.
is there any way to configure this behavior using AKS or Kubernetes in general?

Say I have XYZ API running two replicas/instances.

- XYZ-1 pod instance
- XYZ-2 pod instance

I have some rest API requests to the app domain.com/testendpoint

Currently, using AKS load balancer it sends the requests in a round-robin fashion to XYZ-1 and XYZ-2. I am looking to see if it is possible to forward a request to both instances (XYZ-1 and XYZ-2) when the request endpoint is `testendpoint` and all other API requests use the same round-robin order.

The use case to refresh a service in-memory data via a rest call once a day or twice and the rest call will be triggered by another service when needed. so want to make sure all pod instances update/refresh in-memory data by an HTTP request.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't this what a "load blancer" does? What do you mean with "to all instances" - that it should broadcast your request or use round robin to distribute load to the instances? "all instances" - you mean all replicas of an app, or to all different pods - for different apps - why would you like that?

Comment: There are some requests that I want to forward to all pod instances. I updated my question now.

Comment: How do you plan do handle the responses? If the client receives both responses - its an error - must not happen.

Comment: What's the purpose of the call? Should there be a return value? If it is to do some work on all instances try a messaging service like event grid and have all instances listen to an event.

Comment: This is to refresh in-memory data via a call once a day or twice and the call will be triggered by another service when needed. so want to make sure all pod instances update/refresh in memory data by HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it is possible to forward a request to both instances (XYZ-1 and XYZ-2) when the request endpoint is testendpoint

This is not a feature in the HTTP protocol, so you need a purpose built service to handle this.

> The use case to refresh a service in-memory data via a rest call once a day or twice and the rest call will be triggered by another service when needed. so want to make sure all pod instances update/refresh in-memory data by an HTTP request.

I suggest that you create a new utility service, "update-service" - that you send the call once a day to. This service then makes a request to every instance of XYZ, like `XYZ-1` and `XYZ-2`.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for the response. Is there any AKS (or K8S) API's available to achieve this to find all instances and send requests to those?

Comment: If `XYZ` is deployed as a StatefulSet (instead of Deployment), then this is easy, since your Pods will have the name as you wrote, `XYZ-0`, `XYZ-1` ...depending on how many replicas you have. For Deployment, it is easies to query Pods with the same labels as in your "selector", using a library, e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go or https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

Comment: Instead of using a Kubernetes client (and setting up the required permissions / service accounts) you might consider using an additional headless service that doesn’t have its own cluster ip and load balancing but instead returns all healthy pod ips when doing a dns lookup. See https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8